# How to Change the color of a div with only JS (not jquery) and without an ID or onclick on the element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So when I click c1 I want it to turn black (just c1) and the back to red when clicked again.  Same for c2 and c3.  So I want to do this without IDs and without putting onclick"" on the elements. Oh did I forget to mention no jQuery :]  I know it has to do with using select.  This is purely for learning/trying purposes.

http://jsfiddle.net/hy58knvc/

```
???
```

Comment: You can't do this without click events if you want to change the bgcolor when you click it

Comment: Why can't you use onClick ?

Comment: I think he means no `onclick=""` on the element

Comment: Correct on the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
var circles= document.querySelectorAll('.circle');

for(var i = 0 ; i < circles.length ; i++) {
  circles[i].onclick= function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor= this.style.backgroundColor === 'black' ? 'red' : 'black';
  }
}
```

The first line queries for all elements of class `circle`.

It then assigns an `onclick` handler to each, which toggles the background color.

### Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Using a wrapper (for event delegation) and the [element.classlist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.classList) api:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <!--Start C1-->
    <div class="contain"><div class="circle move-1">1</div></div>
<!--End C1-->
<!--Start C2-->
    <div class="contain"><div class="circle move-1">2</div></div>
<!--End C2-->
<!--Start C3-->
    <div class="contain"><div class="circle move-1">3</div></div>
<!--End C3-->
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('circle')) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('active');
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
   background: blue;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4cuxw17/)**

Answer (score -1):

you could also make use of the event passed by click-handler

for example if you want to use onclick-attribute (warning, bad practice, google it)

```
onclick="foo(event)"

function foo(event){
   event.target.style.backgroundColor="black";
}
```